# Check for Existing Account then create login session after checkout | woo code snippet

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I hope someone can help me...

I need this for (functions.php) snippet edited so after successful checkout on woocommerce (with existing email) the user can access a protected page with there  user role customer.  So a login session needs to be created after checkout.

With the code below can someone edit it so AFTER the existing account checks out and paid that account is logged in with there user role.

PS the code below works, but need the user to be logged in after to access the redirected page.

```
`/**
* Check for Existing Account code snippet
* @param {object} $data the http post data from the checkout form
*
* @return $data
*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 10, 1);
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_posted_data( $data) {
// Exit function if user is logged in to let checkout process as normal
if ( is_user_logged_in()) {
return $data;
}

/*
* If we have a user, we need to set the WP current user so that
* WooCommerce has a user and doesn't think it needs
* to create another one for that user's email.
* If an existing user is not found, then create a new one.
*/
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout()) {
// Make sure not logged in and are on checkout page.
$user = get_user_by('email', $data['billing_email']);if ( !empty($user->ID) ) {
wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
$data['createaccount'] = 0; // Unset flag to create a new user.
}
else {
$data['createaccount'] = 1; // Set the flag to create a new user.
}
}`
```

Thank you in advance for your help!